# moving duplicated directories back to root directory

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I accidentally ended up with a bunch of my directories getting borked, what should be:

```
/myroot/mydirectory
```

ended up as:

```
/myroot/mydirecotry/mydirectory/mydirectory
```

Then nesting could be any where from 1 to N times - I need to find the furthest out /mydirectory and copy all of those files back to the root and kill the duped ones.  How do I find the one that is furthest out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] dirs;
string actualDir = @"\myroot\";
string subdir = "mydirectory";

do
{
    dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(actualDir, subdir);
    actualDir += subdir + @"\";
}
while (dirs.Length > 0);

string theLongestPath = actualDir; // The path to the furthest dir
```

This gets all directories in `actualDir` that contains `subdir`, until it's the last one (no other subdirectories containing `subdir`). If you have any questions on how it works, ask in a comment. And yeah, I've tried it, it really works.

Comment: Well, I forgot to tell you, the `Directory.GetDirectories(string path, string searchPatterns)` will return also names of directories that contains `subdir`, but whose name is longer than that. If you really want to be sure that there's a subdirectory called _mydirectory_, and not only for example _thisismydirectory_, you'll have to go thru the `dirs` array and check one by one, which may be a bit complicated, ugh...

Comment: nice, much cleaner than the recursive function call I ended up creating

Comment: Thanks. Could you accept the answer as noone else responded with anything better and this works?